# Finding 2 random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm looking for 2 random variables $X,Y$ S.T $P(X+Y=1)=1$ and $X,Y$ are related.

Any ideas? (maybe using them short story will make it clear, ie X is number of etc...)

Plus, how can I show that they are related, for 2 events $A,B$ we can show that $P(A \& B) != P(A) P(B)$ but what about random variables?

Comment: Flip a coin once. $X$ = number of heads and $Y$ = number of tails. Two (discrete) random variables are independent if $\mathbb P(X=x, Y=y)=\mathbb P(X=x)\mathbb P(Y=y)$ for all values of $x,y$. So you just need to show this is not true in this case.

Comment: Related meaning not independent? I'm assuming by the $!$ you meant $\neq$?

Comment: @jlammy thanks, what if I want only X+Y=U(0,2) ? (while they are not independent)

Comment: without the request that P(X+Y=1)=1